# Delete and Edit post entry for simple Blog on PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, edit, blogs

Created this script based on a tutorial but I would like to add a few things, one is able to edit and delete the post. This code works but I honestly do not know much about php, how can include such features as this script?

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogData (title, category, content) VALUE('$title', '$category',  '$content')");
echo "Data has been posted, <a href='index.php'>go index</a>. - <a href='admin.php'>Other Post</a>";
}else{
?>

<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'>
  <div class='form-group'>
        <form class='control-label' action='admin.php' method='post'>
        Titulo <input class='form-control' type='text' name='title' /><br />
        Categoria <input class='form-control' type='text' name='category' /><br />
        Contenido <textarea class='form-control' rows='9' name='content'></textarea><br />
    <input class='btn btn-default btn-block' type='submit' name='submit' value='Post' />
    <br><br><br>

    <ul class='breadcrumb'>
      <li><a href='index.php'>index</a></li>
      <li><a href='logout.php'>logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">      
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: @Strawberry Actually, MySQL does accept both `VALUE` and `VALUES`, *strangely enough*. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html - `INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE}` <=

Comment: You're kidding! Well, guess you learn something every day! ;-)

Comment: Start by reading the manuals http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html then Google from there.

Comment: @Strawberry I learned that myself about 5-6 months ago when I saw a similar question, but I quickly turned to Google and MySQL.com to see if it was in fact valid. Lo and behold, it was.

Comment: As it stands, you have SQL injection vulnerabilities in your database query. Consider switching to a library that supports parameterisation (either PDO or mysqli) in order to avoid this.

Comment: There's a problem with your tutorial. You're using the mysql_ extension (mysql_query() ect...) which are deprecated and in some ways insecure. Look for a different tutorial, using PDO or MySQLi_ (or both, to see which one you prefer). That said, the actual mysql queries are the same either way, and they support "update" and "delete" queries.

Answer (score -1):

Use the PHP Mysql DELETE statement to delete the post, and PHP Mysql UPDATE statement to edit the existing post.. its so simple

Comment: You could, at the very least, include links as well as an example. The links would need to be taken from MySQL.com http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html

Comment: Plus, PHP DELETE/UPDATE. PHP has nothing to do with it, it's MySQL. Do give correct information.